# Why volatile is not enough?

Tags: c#, synchronization

I'm confused. Answers to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516940/can-multiple-cpus-simultaneously-write-to-the-same-ram-location) seems to confirm my assumptions. But as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154551/volatile-vs-interlocked-vs-lock) volatile is not enough to assure atomicity in .Net. Either operations like incrementation and assignment in MSIL are not translated directly to single, native OPCODE or many CPUs can simultaneously read and write to the same RAM location.

To clarify:

1. I want to know if writes and reads are atomic on multiple CPUs?
2. I understand what volatile is about. But is it enough? Do I need to use interlocked operations if I want to get latest value writen by other CPU?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Herb Sutter recently wrote an article on `volatile` and what it really means (how it affects ordering of memory access and atomicity) in the native C++. .NET, and Java environments. It's a pretty good read:

- [volatile vs. volatile](https://web.archive.org/web/20090421134427/http://www.ddj.com/hpc-high-performance-computing/212701484)

Comment: It *is* a pretty good read (and definitely deserves a +1), but it's normally preferred for SO answers to be somewhat self-contained. It'd be nice if your answer contained a summary of the important parts of that article, just so (1) people skimming the page will see it, and (2) so the answer stays relevant if the article is moved or taken down.

Answer (score 6):

volatile in .NET does make access to the variable atomic.

The problem is, that's often not enough. What if you need to read the variable, and if it is 0 (indicating that the resource is free), you set it to 1 (indicating that it's locked, and other threads should stay away from it).

Reading the 0 is atomic. Writing the 1 is atomic. But between those two operations, anything might happen. You might read a 0, and then before you can write the 1, another thread jumps in, reads the 0, and writes an 1.

However, volatile in .NET *does* guarantee atomicity of accesses to the variable. It just doesn't guarantee thread safety for operations relying on multiple accesses to it. (Disclaimer: volatile in C/C++ does not even guarantee this. Just so you know. It is much weaker, and occasinoally a source of bugs because people assume it guarantees atomicity :))

So you need to use locks as well, to group together multiple operations as one thread-safe chunk. (Or, for simple operations, the `Interlocked` operations in .NET may do the trick)

Comment: Note, that it's not volatile that guarantees atomicity to variables - it's the other way around: if a variable can be accessed atomically, `volatile` can be applied to it.

Answer (score 5):

I might be jumping the gun here but it sounds to me as though you're confusing two issues here.

One is atomicity, which in my mind means that a single operation (that may require multiple steps) should not come in conflict with another such single operation.

The other is volatility, when is this value expected to change, and why.

Take the first. If your two-step operation requires you to read the current value, modify it, and write it back, you're most certainly going to want a lock, unless this whole operation can be translated into a single CPU instruction that can work on a single cache-line of data.

However, the second issue is, even when you're doing the locking thing, what will other threads see.

A `volatile` field in .NET is a field that the compiler knows can change at arbitrary times. In a single-threaded world, the change of a variable is something that happens at some point in a sequential stream of instructions so the compiler knows when it has added code that changes it, or at least when it has called out to outside world that may or may not have changed it so that once the code returns, it might not be the same value it was before the call.

This knowledge allows the compiler to lift the value from the field into a register once, before a loop or similar block of code, and never re-read the value from the field for that particular code.

With multi-threading however, that might give you some problems. One thread might have adjusted the value, and another thread, due to optimization, won't be reading this value for some time, because it *knows* it hasn't changed.

So when you flag a field as `volatile` you're basically telling the compiler that it shouldn't assume that it has the current value of this at any point, except for grabbing snapshots every time it needs the value.

Locks solve multiple-step operations, volatility handles how the compiler caches the field value in a register, and together they will solve more problems.

Also note that if a field contains something that cannot be read in a single cpu-instruction, you're most likely going to want to lock read-access to it as well.

For instance, if you're on a 32-bit cpu and writing a 64-bit value, that write-operation will require two steps to complete, and if another thread on another cpu manages to read the 64-bit value before step 2 has completed, it will get half of the previous value and half of the new, nicely mixed together, which can be even worse than getting an outdated one.

---

**Edit**: To answer the comment, that `volatile` guarantees the atomicity of the read/write operation, that's well, true, in a way, because the `volatile` keyword cannot be applied to fields that are larger than 32-bit, in effect making the field single-cpu-instruction read/writeable on both 32 and 64-bit cpu's. And yes, it will prevent the value from being kept in a register as much as possible.

So part of the comment is wrong, `volatile` cannot be applied to 64-bit values.

Note also that `volatile` has some semantics regarding reordering of reads/writes.

For relevant information, see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) or the [C# specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc), found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx), section 10.5.3.

Comment: Just to be clear, your description of volatile sounds more like the one found in C/C++. In .net, volatile does guarantee atomicity as well as forcing it to be kept in memory, rather than a register. Even on larger values, like 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

On a hardware level, multiple CPUs can never write simultanously to the same atomic RAM location. The size of an atomic read/write operation dependeds on CPU architecture, but is typically 1, 2 or 4 bytes on a 32-bit architecture. However, if you try reading the result back there is always a chance that another CPU has made a write to the same RAM location inbetween. On a low level, spin-locks are typically used to synchronize access to shared memory. In a high level language, such mechanisms may be called e.g. critical regions.

The volatile type just makes sure the variable is written immediately back to memory when it is changed (even if the value is to be used in the same function). A compiler will usually keep a value in an internal register for as long as possible if the value is to be reused later in the same function, and it is stored back to RAM when all modifications are finished or when a function returns. Volatile types are mostly useful when writing to hardware registers, or when you want to be sure a value is stored back to RAM in e.g. a multithread system.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't entirely make sense, because [volatile specifies the how the read happens](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/06/13/VolatileReadsAndWritesAndTimeliness.aspx), not atomicity of multi-step processes. My car doesn't mow my lawn, either, but I try not to hold that against it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes in with register based cashed copies of your variable's values.

When reading a value, the cpu will first see if it's in a register (fast) before checking main memory (slower).

Volatile tells the compiler to push the value out to main memory asap, and not to trust the cached register value.  It's only useful in certain cases.

If you're looking for single op code writes, you'll need to use the Interlocked.Increment related methods..  But they're fairly limited in what they can do in a single safe instruction.

Safest and most reliable bet is to lock() (if you can't do an Interlocked.*)

Edit:  Writes and reads are atomic if they're in a lock or an interlocked.* statement.  Volatile alone is not enough under the terms of your question

Answer (score -1):

Volatile is a compiler keyword that tells the compiler what to do. It does not necessarily translate into (essentially) bus operations that are required for atomicity. That is usually left up to the operating system.

Edit: to clarify, volatile is never enough if you want to guarantee atomicity. Or rather, it's up to the compiler to make it enough or not.

Comment: duh. but what about incrementation and assignment?

Comment: If you are talking about interlocked operations, i.e., guaranteed atomic operations, those two need to be implemented either by bus operations (x86 uses the lock opcode modifier) or the OS (PPC needs to use lwarx/stwrx to do the equivalent).

Comment: Why would a bus operation be required for atomicity especially if your CPU is one of Core2Duo's? And left up to the OS? You've *got* to be kidding!

Comment: @Zach, well, I should have been more explicit. You really just need to ensure cache coherency between processors/cores, so cache control opcodes are usually sufficient. However, in the context of whether `volatile` is enough to synchronize multiple threads, it obviously isn't.